# Excel VBA Application.PrintCommunication not working anymore with network printer

Tags: vba, excel

I always found my answers here in the past so I hope one of you Genius out there could pull one more trick for me.  Here's the situation.
I've created a small application in Excel 2016 a couple of years ago.  It's been running for 2 years now flawlessly.  I have to say that it was at my previous job (but I still do kind of after sale service here...).  Anyway, lately they moved to Office 365 and then kaboom!  They can't use the feature that prints the report created.
The error is

> Run time error 1004   Method 'PrintCommunication' of object
>   '_Application' failed

Remember that before they switch to Office 365.  Everything was working fine.
Also, you have to know that if you use a local printer (plugged with a USB cable) it works perfectly (just like before).  This method (local printer) was tested on 2 computers and works fine.  But it won't work if it's a network printer in the company.

EDIT:  I've just found out that it works in some part of the company and not in one.  For example, it works fine for the employees of all provinces (we're in Canada:  provinces are the equivalent of States in the US) except for one.  So there must be something that is not compatible with a parameter on a server or something like that.  Does it help someone?
END of EDIT

I've looked around here and on other sites.  I've tried pretty much all the tricks about "commenting out"  lines like "print quality = 600" and other stuff like that.

Below is the code.  The error is at line

```
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

4 lines before the `"End Sub"`  .  The other line when I switch `.printCommunication = True`  there is no error there

```
Sub imprime_feuille_identification(trois_feuille)
'
    Sheets("IDENTIFICATION").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MOYENS_CONTROLE").Cells(9, 16384) = ActiveSheet.Name             'identifie de quelle feuille vient la demande d'impression sert à y revenir ensuite
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MOYENS_CONTROLE").Cells(10, 16384) = ""                           'va servir à identifier qu'on veut imprimer une seule feuille
    Range("A1:P38").Select
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$P$38"                                              'définition de la zone d'impression
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$2:$2"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$P$38"
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = " &9&P de &N   "
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(9.84251968503937E-02)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(9.84251968503937E-02)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(9.84251968503937E-02)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(9.84251968503937E-02)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.196850393700787)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.196850393700787)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        '.PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        '.PrintComments = False 'xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600                'Tried to comment out this line:  still get the error
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 0
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True     'THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE'

    If trois_feuille <> 1 Then                  'si le sub a été appelé en dehors du sub "imprime trois feuille" alors on fait
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")                                 'affiche la page d'impression
    End If    
End Sub
```

So anyone, any bright idea and solution?  Don't hesitate to ask precision if my explanations of the problem are not clear.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is being caused by the line

```
.Zoom = False
```

When setting the Zoom property via VBA, you must set .Zoom = integer value between 10 and 400 (e.g., `.Zoom = 25`) if you want to control scaling using the zoom method. The value is converted to percentages by Excel (e.g., 10% to 400%) and then used as a multiplier.

If you want to control the number of pages wide and tall then use the properties `.FitToPagesWide = some Integer` and `.FitToPagesTall = some Integer`.

If you use the `.FitTo... properties` then .Zoom is set to false by Excel not the VBA code.  Here is a link to MS Documentation explaining the use of [.Zoom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-zoom-property-excel) property.

So you'll need to remove or comment out either the `.Zoom = False` line or the two lines

```
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 0
```

Comment: But then why is it working fine if the printer use is connected via USB cable?  Someone else agree with that suggestion?  And also remember that it worked for 2 years without problems.

Comment: I did some more digging.  I also found that the line `.PrintQuality = 600` is probably also causing some problems.  The USB printer may support a configuration of 600dpi, the network printer might have something like "High Quality", which is what I found testing on a couple of printers I have.  If I set the `.PrinterQuality = 600` on the network printer I got the error, because it doesn't support a 600 dpi setting.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-printquality-property-excel) states that PrintQuality may cause an error depending on the printer driver.

Comment: If PrintQuality setting is where the error is occurring, it would not occur while communication with the printer is off.  From the additional research I did, there are numerous questions/answers to this problem on the Internet, many here on StackOverFlow.  It is also possible that it had been working until the update to Office 365, which may have included new printer drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your effort Jamie but as I stated in the description of the problem   "I've looked around here and on other sites. I've tried pretty much all the tricks about "commenting out" lines like "print quality = 600" and other stuff like that. "  Thank you very much for you efforts and research but still no luck with this.

Comment: You bet.  I think this problem boils down to interaction between Excel, the operating system, the print drivers, the network drivers and the printer itself.